# Winforms: Generic host form for different user controls?

Tags: winforms, user-controls

I'm working on a Winforms project that will have several "lookup" style user controls.  These controls could be embedded on various forms, but will usually be stand-alone.  I'd like to design a Windows form that could host a generic user control and perform several of the tasks common to these lookups.  My brain is telling me to do this, but this obviously does not work:

```
public partial class LookupHostForm<TUserControl> : Form where TUserControl : UserControl
```

Is there a way that I can use one form to host several user controls without the form knowing/caring what the user control is?

Comment: What do you mean that it does not work? The designer may not resolve properly, but once you're done with the basic design, I don't see why the code wouldn't work at runtime.

Comment: It breaks `InitializeComponent()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way a form "hosts" a user control is by adding the instance of the user control to the form as a child control. Each form has a public [`Controls` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) that exposes a `ControlsCollection` class. That is a collection of all child controls hosted by that form.

All you have to do is add your user control to the form's Controls collection. This will have exactly the effect that you want. For example:

```
CustomUserControl uc = new CustomUserControl();
myForm.Controls.Add(uc);
```

To polish off the effect, you might also want to dock the user control to fill the entire client area of its host form, or anchor it to all four sides. Docking will cause the size of the user control to change when its host form's size changes. Anchoring will just center the user control in the middle of its host. Use the appropriately-named [`Dock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) and [`Anchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) properties of your user control to achieve this effect.

And of course, *any* form object can do this. I would subclass the `Form` class and expose a strongly-typed method to add instances of my user controls to its controls collection. For example:

```
public class HostForm : Form
{
    public void SetChildControl<TUserControl>(TUserControl ctrl) where TUserControl : UserControl
    {
        // Add the specified user control to the forms controls collection
        this.Controls.Add(ctrl);

        // Dock the user control in its host form
        ctrl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, I am aware of the "how."  What I'm looking for is a way for `myForm.Controls.Add(new CustomUserControl())` to not have to know the type of `CustomUserControl`.

Comment: @AJ: That's the easy part. You can use generics just like you first tried. But instead of overloading the form's constructor (which you say interferes with `InitializeComponent`, you can just expose a public method that internally calls `this.Controls.Add()`.

Comment: Excellent, I like this approach, because I can create a base interface for my lookup controls and it appears to load faster than it does with reflection.  Thanks!

Comment: @AJ: Yeah, I definitely wouldn't use Reflection for something like this. I suspect there's probably a way of achieving this by overloading the constructor, too, but I didn't try to investigate that since it didn't seem crucial that you have this logic in the ctor. I'm glad this works for you!

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do as you need.

Just add a constructor that takes the type or an instance of the UserControl you would like. Then add it as a child control of the form in the constructor. Or add a virtual method that creates the specific control of interest and you have a derived class for each variation you need where each derived class overrides the virtual and returns the correct type. Or have a property that specifies the control. Lots of ways to do it.

Comment: "...add a constructor that takes the type..."  How would I do this?  `public void new(Type userControlType...)` and then use `Activator.CreateInstance` or something like it?